# How to compare Euler's method to a second-Order Runge-Kutta Method at the same stepsize?

Tags: python, matplotlib, numeric, differential-equations, runge-kutta

I have two algorithms for a numerical differential equation problem, one called Euler's method and one called a second-order Runge Kutta(RK2) . Essentially Euler's method and RK2 approximate a solution to differential equations. The only difference is that they use different formulas (Euler's uses a first order derivative  of Taylor's series whilst the RK2 is a second order derivative of a Taylor series).

I am trying to correct some code that I have written in order for it to return the  following solution,
[image]

However my code is not returning the correct values when it comes to the RK2 but returns the following,

[image]

Note that in my solution I refer to the step size h as dt. I have provided the code that I used to create this below followed by a numeric example of the second-order Runge Kutta method that is working numerically. I am interested in showing that the convergence is quicker with the RK2 than Euler's method.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import exp  # exponential function

dy = lambda x, y: x * y
f = lambda x: exp(x ** 2 / 2)  # analytical solution function
x_final = 2

# analytical solution
x_a = np.arange(0, x_final, 0.01)
y_a = np.zeros(len(x_a))
for i in range(len(x_a)):
    y_a[i] = f(x_a[i])
plt.plot(x_a, y_a, label="analytical")

# Container for step sizes dt /dt
dt = 0.5

x = 0
y = 1
print("dt = " + str(dt))
print("x \t\t y (Euler) \t y (analytical)")
print("%f \t %f \t %f" % (x, y, f(x)))

n = int((x_final - x) / dt)

x_n = np.zeros(n + 1)
y_n = np.zeros(n + 1)
x_n[0] = x
y_n[0] = y

#Plot Euler's method
for i in range(n):
    y += dy(x, y) * dt
    x += dt
    print("%f \t %f \t %f" % (x, y, f(x)))
    x_n[i + 1] = x
    y_n[i + 1] = y

plt.plot(x_n, y_n, "x-", label="Euler dt=" + str(dt))

###################33
# Runge-Kutta's method 2'nd order (RK2)
x = 0
y = 1
print("dt = " + str(dt))
print("x \t\t y (rk2) \t y (analytical)")
print("%f \t %f \t %f" % (x, y, f(x)))

n = int((x_final - x) / dt)

x_n = np.zeros(n + 1)
y_n = np.zeros(n + 1)
x_n[0] = x
y_n[0] = y

# Plot the RK2
for z in range(n):
    K1 = dt*dy(x,y) # Step 1
    K2 = dt*dy(x+dt/2,y+K1/K2) # Step 2
    y += K2 # Step 3
    x += dt
    print("%f \t %f \t %f" % (x, y, f(x)))
    x_n[i + 1] = x
    y_n[i + 1] = y

plt.plot(x_n, y_n, "x-", label="RK2 dt=" + str(dt))

plt.title("Euler's method ")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This is the numeric code that works for the RK2. I have put step 1,2,and 3 on the changes from the the Euler method that allows us to create the RK2.

```
from math import exp
dy = lambda x,y: x*y
f = lambda x: exp(x**2/2)
x = 0
xn = 2
y = 1
dt = 0.5
n = int((xn)/dt)
print ('x \t\t y (RK2) \t y (analytical)')
print ('%f \t %f \t %f'% (x,y,f(x)))
# main loop
for i in range(n):
    K1 = dt*dy(x, y) # step 1
    K2 = dt*dy(x + dt/2, y + K1/2) # step 2
    y += K2  # step 3
    x += dt
    print ('%f \t %f \t %f'% (x,y,f(x)))
```

Sorry If I have asked this question badly. I am new to python, so I am still trying to understand how to go about solving these types of problems. The summary of my question is how can I fix the above function in order to calculate the correct estimate and then plot it on the graph using matplotlib from python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two small details:

1. In the RK-2 loop you're using z, but to store the values you use i
2. In the initial code, you were using y+K1/K2 when you update K2 and that's wrong. I see you fix it in the second code.

So, the fixed code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import exp  # exponential function

dy = lambda x, y: x * y
f = lambda x: exp(x ** 2 / 2)  # analytical solution function
x_final = 2

# analytical solution
x_a = np.arange(0, x_final, 0.01)
y_a = np.zeros(len(x_a))
for i in range(len(x_a)):
    y_a[i] = f(x_a[i])

plt.plot(x_a, y_a, label="analytical")

# Container for step sizes dt /dt
dt = 0.5

x = 0
y = 1
print("dt = " + str(dt))
print("x \t\t y (Euler) \t y (analytical)")
print("%f \t %f \t %f" % (x, y, f(x)))

n = int((x_final - x) / dt)

x_e = np.zeros(n + 1)
y_e = np.zeros(n + 1)
x_e[0] = x
y_e[0] = y

#Plot Euler's method
for i in range(n):
    y += dy(x, y) * dt
    x += dt
    print("%f \t %f \t %f" % (x, y, f(x)))
    x_e[i + 1] = x
    y_e[i + 1] = y

plt.plot(x_e, y_e, "x-", label="Euler dt=" + str(dt))

###################33
# Runge-Kutta's method 2'nd order (RK2)
x = 0
y = 1
print("dt = " + str(dt))
print("x \t\t y (rk2) \t y (analytical)")
print("%f \t %f \t %f" % (x, y, f(x)))

n = int((x_final - x) / dt)

x_r = np.zeros(n + 1)
y_r = np.zeros(n + 1)
x_r[0] = x
y_r[0] = y

# Plot the RK2
for i in range(n):
    K1 = dt*dy(x,y) # Step 1
    K2 = dt*dy(x+dt/2,y+K1/2) # Step 2
    y += K2 # Step 3
    x += dt
    print("%f \t %f \t %f" % (x, y, f(x)))
    x_r[i + 1] = x
    y_r[i + 1] = y

plt.plot(x_r, y_r, "s-", label="RK2 dt=" + str(dt))

plt.title("numerical differential equation problem")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```